# Putting objects into a list into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, object, dictionary

I'm trying to create a Google Ngram-esque program in Python (CS-I project). I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
aardvark, 2007, 123948
aardvark, 2008, 120423
aardvark, 2004, 96323
gorilla, 2010, 120302
gorilla, 2008, 89323
raptorjesus, 1996, 214
```

The first value represents the word, the second the year we're counting the number of occurrences in, and the third the number of occurrences.

I have a class `CountByYear` that takes in word, year, and frequency and returns a CountByYear object.

I need to read through the CSV file and print a dictionary containing the words as keys with lists of CountByYear objects as values (without the words). For example:

```
{'aardvark': [CountByYear(year=2007, count=123948), CountByYear(year=2008...etc.], 'gorilla: [CountByYear(year=2010, count=120302), etc...)]
```

I'm stuck on how I'm actually supposed to get the year and count for each object. Right now I'm doing:

```
for line in f:
    splitLine = line.strip().split(',')
    words[splitLine[0]] = countList
print(words)
```

which prints `{aardvark': [], 'gorilla': [], 'raptorjesus': []` and this is good because at least I know I'm doing the dictionary part properly. But how do I fill those empty lists with the data I want?

Comment: You can't just make `count` and `year` class attributes and call `CountByYear.count`, or am I completely misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't include the example of the CountByYear class but you specify it has a constructor that takes "word", "year", and "frequency".

Assuming a definition like this:

```
class CountByYear(object):
    def __init__(self, word, year, frequency):
        self.word = word
        self.year = year
        self.frequency = frequency

    def __repr__(self):
        return "CountByYear(year=%s, count=%s)" % (self.year, self.frequency)
```

You can do something like this:

```
words = {}
for line in f:
    word,year,freq = [i.strip() for i in line.split(',')]
    #create a new list if one does not already exist for this word
    if not words.get(word):
        words[word] = []
    #add this CountByYear object to corresponding list in the dictionary
    words[word].append(CountByYear(word,year,freq))
print(words)
```

The output from the above code on your example input file would be:

```
{'gorilla': [CountByYear(year=2010, count=120302), CountByYear(year=2008, count=89323)], 'aardvark': [CountByYear(year=2007, count=123948), CountByYear(year=2008, count=120423), CountByYear(year=2004, count=96323)], 'raptorjesus': [CountByYear(year=1996, count=214)]}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be using [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). For example,

```
from collections import defaultdict

words = defaultdict(list)

with open("data.csv", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        key_name, year, count = line.rstrip().split(',')
        words[key_name] += [year, count]
        # or  words[key_name] += CountByYear(year, count) or similar

print(words)
```

Comment: how is += being used here?  is it calling .append() on the default (empty) list?  Is there some preference for using this instead of .append()?

Comment: I use `defaultdict`, not regular dict. with `defaultdict` the synatx and appending to dictionaries of lists appears more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `csv` module ( https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html ) and something like

```
import csv

words = {}
with open('eggs.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')

    for word, year, count in reader:
        words[word] = words.get(word, []) + [CountByYear(word, year, count)]

print(words)
```